# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, web

I'm creating an application for my site but I keep getting this error when compiling and running it (It worked without errors before tho !!!)

```
dRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.sp.omar.spray, PID: 3914
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sp.omar.spray/com.sp.omar.spray.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
```

Here's my onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendEmail();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        displayView(R.id.nav_home);

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        WebView sprayWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.spraySite);
        String url = "https://spray.000webhostapp.com/spray/spray/html/index.html";

        WebSettings spraySettings = sprayWeb.getSettings();
        spraySettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        spraySettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        sprayWeb.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        sprayWeb.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        sprayWeb.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/spraySite"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

HomeFragment.class:

```
package com.sp.omar.spray;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreateView(inflater, group, savedInstanceState);
            final View homeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, group, false);
            Home homeActivity = new Home();
            homeActivity.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            return homeView;
        }

    }
```

Home.class:

```
package com.sp.omar.spray;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

/**
 * Created by i0mar on 12/28/2016.
 */

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView sprayWeb;
    private String url;
    private WebSettings spraySettings;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        sprayWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.spraySite);
        url = "https://spray.000webhostapp.com/spray/spray/html/index.html";

        spraySettings = sprayWeb.getSettings();
        spraySettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        spraySettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        sprayWeb.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        sprayWeb.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        sprayWeb.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

and I've added the WebView to a secondary xml file not the activity_main one cuz it's a navigation drawer app and I want that WebView to be only in one page.
If anyone know how to fix it please tell me and thanks :)

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: A webview with "spraySite" as id should be there in your "activity_main".You have defined it in some other layout.And thus you are getting null oblect for "sprayWeb"

Comment: @i0mar you cannot call a view that is not connected/linked to an activity , You have a web view in your home xml . Is there any connection that you establish between your home.xml and activity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no id name "spraySite" int your "activity_main" xml layout.

so your sprayWeb is a null object.

Comment: There's but not in my activity_main.xml

Comment: it must be in your activity_main.xml

Comment: But I don't want the WebView to be on my activity_main, how can I point to the WebView on my other xml file ???

Comment: @i0mar Start a new activity with the layout where you defined "spraySite".And change all the code of web to that activity.

Comment: @sunil sunny I've already tried that with my HomeFragment.java but it didn't work

Comment: @i0mar, you can make you webView on other xml, but you should make actvity_main.xml include that xml. If not, it will raise NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Please, post your xml files: `activity_main.xml` and that file where you add your `webView` with id "spraySite". The problem is that you still tried to get your `WebView` from `activity_main`.

Comment: Done, sry for that

Comment: As i understand your wishes: should make two fragments: at the first put all code from activity_main.xml, at the second put all your code from home.xml. For example, HomeFragment.java and MainFragment.java. Activity_main.xml should have only container for this fragments. And in the java code you should just replace your fragments as you wish dynamically. Do you know how to do it, or need link to explanation?If you already tried this and that doesn't work, please, post all your code, your fragments and activity, java and xml, otherwise it will be difficult to understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: It fixed that error but I got another one "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback null object reference" I'll post my HomeFragment and my Home cass rn

Comment: I recommend you read this article and the next few after that for better understanding what you're doing and why:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: Thanks, I was an idiot, it worked now :)

Comment: Glad to help you :)